# React Route Home Page and Admin Page

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on a React web app to route different pages. Using React Router

**Requirement:**
Totally 2 major parent routes namely (Customer and Admin)
So when user hits ex.: localhost:3000 it should default to homepage (Customer Component) and localhost:3000/admin route to (Admin Page).

**Problem:**
Either I'm only able to route all child components of Customer (or) Admin. Both are not working as properly.

**Currently What is Working?**

- localhost:3000 - Loading Home page
- **localhost:3000/sale - Blank page (need to fix)**
- **localhost:3000/sale/product - Blank page (need to fix)**
- localhost:3000/admin - Loading Admin page
- localhost:3000/admin/all-products - Loading Product List page
- localhost:3000/admin/add-product - Loading Product Detail page

**Files:**
**Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter basename='/'>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Customer} />
                <Route path='/admin' component={Admin} />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}
```

**Customer.js**

```
class Customer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div className='container mainContent'>
                    <Breadcrumbs />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
                        <Route path='/sale' component={ProductList} />
                        <Route path='/sale/product' component={ProductDetails} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Admin.js**

```
class Admin extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container-fluid'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <ul className='sidebar-submenu '>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to='/admin/all-products' activeClassName='active'>All Products</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to='/admin/add-product' activeClassName='active'>>Create Product</NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div className='col-md-10 admin-content'>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path='/admin/all-products' component={ProductListView} />
                            <Route path='/admin/add-product' component={ProductListCreate} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. First, let go through this one:

```
localhost:3000/sale - Blank page (need to fix)
localhost:3000/sale/product - Blank page (need to fix)
```

The reason is at **App.js** file, you have the `exact` prop declared on this line:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Customer} />
```

Which results in the nested routes after `/`, for example, `/sale` or `/sale/product` is not working.

Have you realized it already? Why `/admin/all-products` or `/admin/add-product` route is working fine? Because you dont have the `exact` prop  declared on this line:

```
<Route path='/admin' component={Admin} />
```

So please remove the `exact` prop in `Customer` route to get it work!

2. Second, IMO, you should **seperate** your `Customer` and `Admin` routes from the very beginning. By **seperate**, I mean you have better authenticate your workflow properly. Please have a look at this: [react-router auth-workflow](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

A `Customer` should not have the right to view the `Admin` routes.

---

**Update 1 from Hem's reply:**

> But /admin and its child routes are goes to blank page.

Keep in mind that you are using `Switch` component inside **App.js**. Just like normal `switch/case`, it will match the very first path (case for normal `switch/case`) from top to bottom.

So for your case:

```
<Switch>
 <Route path='/' component={Customer} /> // <- Have no exact here
 <Route path='/admin' component={Admin} />
</Switch>
```

Because the very first path in `Switch` is `/`, so it always goes to the `Customer` route regardlessly. And `/admin` is a nested route of `/`, so it could never reach the `Admin` route.

> Then if add exact to `<Route path='/' component={Home} />` able to
>   switch to `/sale` page and same for `/sale/product`

Yes, like I said before, because you got rid of the `exact` prop in the `Customer` route at **App.js**. Both `/sale` &  `/sale/product` are nested routes of `/`, both `ProductList` & `ProductDetails` are nested components inside `Customer`. It doesnt matter the `exact` is added in the `Home` route or not.

IMO, you have better clear your routing layer in advance:

1. First layer App: `/`
2. Second layer Main (nested routes inside App): `/` for `Customer`, `/admin` for `Admin`
3. Third layer Pages (nested routes inside Main): `/sale`, `/admin/all-products`
4. Fourth layer Nested Pages (nested routes inside Pages): `/sale/product`

Comment: The reason is at **App.js** file, you have the **exact** prop declared 
Agreed there should be a authentication layer.

As you said I've tried already without **exact** and nothing is getting routed other than Home page -  **Home** Component.

`<Route path='/' component={Home} />`
This is not getting **Switching** to next. Sorry to mention this point late.
  
Then if add **exact** to <Route path='/' component={Home} /> able to switch to `/sale` page and same for `/sale/product`. But /admin and its child routes are goes to blank page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
App.js

```
  class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' component={Customer} />
                <Route path='/admin' component={Admin} />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}
```

customer.js

```
 class Customer extends Component {
render() {
    return (
     <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div className='container mainContent'>
                <Breadcrumbs />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path='/sale' component={ProductList} />
                    <Route exact path='/sale/product' component={ProductDetails} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
     </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

admin.js

```
 class Admin extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <BrowserRouter>
            <div className='container-fluid'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <ul className='sidebar-submenu '>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to='/admin/all-products' activeClassName='active'>All Products</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to='/admin/add-product' activeClassName='active'>>Create Product</NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div className='col-md-10 admin-content'>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/admin/all-products' component={ProductListView} />
                            <Route exact path='/admin/add-product' component={ProductListCreate} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom' in both app.js and customer.js file